# Python - AttributeError: 'MyLogger' object has no attribute 'ui'

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm new on python and objects and sorry, I need help. :)
When I run my code obtain this error: "Python - AttributeError: 'MyLogger' object has no attribute 'ui'".

It's because I'm using two classes?
As I can change the value of progressbar?

This is my code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from Musicdl import *
import sys, youtube_dl, re, threading

class Musicdl(QtGui.QDialog):
     def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Window()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.button_download,     QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), start_thread)

class MyLogger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        get_progressvalue(self, msg)
    def warning(self, msg):
        pass
    def error(self, msg):
        pass

def start_thread():
    t = threading.Thread(target=download)
    t.start()

def my_hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'finished':
        print('Descarga completada. Convirtiendo ...')

ydl_opts = {
    "progress_with_newline": True,
    "outtmpl": "%(title)s.%(ext)s",
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '320',
    }],
    'logger': MyLogger(),
    'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
}

progressvalue = int(0)

def get_progressvalue(self, msg):
    global progressvalue
    match = re.match(r'\[\w+\]\s+(\d{1,3})', msg)
    if match:
        value = int(match.group(1))
        if value != progressvalue:
            progressvalue = value
            print(progressvalue)
            self.ui.progressbar.setValue(10)

def download():
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download(['...'])
        print('Terminado.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Musicdl()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Sorry for writting all code but I don't know what to do on this.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Why do you think `MyLogger` *would* have a `ui`attribute?

Comment: MyLogger doesn't have a ui attribute, but the get_progressvalue function need it for change the value of progressbar on the gui and it's included in the MyLogger class. The questin is, how to use the ui attribute of Musicdl class on get_progressbar function. Sorry but I'm new on this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `get_progressvalue()` is called with first parameter as logger.

```
self.ui.progressbar.setValue(10)
```

This is the line that produces the error along with (inside `MyLogger`)

```
    def debug(self, msg):
        get_progressvalue(self, msg)
```

I suspect that self in get_progressvalue has to be replaced by the Musicdl object's self instead of MyLogger's.

---

Saw your comment, what you should do is pass in Musicdls self to myLoggers initializer. Even better would be to only pass in musicdls ui attribute.

```
class MyLogger(object):
    def __init__(self, musicdl=None):
        self.musicdl = musicdl
    def debug(self, msg):
        get_progressvalue(self.musicdl, msg)
    def warning(self, msg):
        pass
    def error(self, msg):
        pass
```

This is not the best solution, but for it to work you have to change the `ydl_opts["logger"]` entry to `MyLogger(musicdl=myapp)` in the "if name main loop".

Comment: Hi Emilgardis, thanks for you response but if I change the lines of MyLogger class as you said, i obtain this error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ui'". I'm sorry for inconvenience, I will read more about objects on python. Thanks you!!

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, you need to use the keyword argument `musicdl`, I'll update my answer. It is wierd though that it didn't complain about a unneeded positional argument

Comment: Also, next time you have a question, be sure to mention what line the error is on. It makes it easier for us to localize the problem.

Comment: As you said, this is not the best solution but works!! :) Thanks you!!

Comment: No problem, be sure to mark my answer as the solution :)